# Needing help locating a specific verse in the Bible about casting out bad influences?

Tags: verse-identification

This might be a fool's errand, but it's my hope that someone out there more able than me will have an idea of what I'm talking about (I'm not sure my explanation is going to be very good and it will just cause headaches).

The other day, I found a verse about essentially standing up to people and/or bad influences and forcing them out of your life.  I feel like it had a lot to do with being complicit in your own misery, that evil or pain only has as much power over you as you allow it to have in your life...and I can't for the life of me find it anywhere.  I wish I had written it down.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm talking about?  Or any good leads?  I remember it being fairly short, fairly simple.  I have a suspicion it might be a Psalm or a Proverb, but I don't want to assume that and end up being way off.  Please, any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: What kind of bad influences are you asking about: people, places, evil spirits or all of them?

Answer (score 4):

The advice in James 4:7 to resist the devil is sound.  But first we have to “Submit yourselves, then, to God."  We can't do it in our own strength.

Ephesians 6:12 describes the forces that believers face:

> “For our struggle is not against flesh and blood, but against the rulers, against the powers, against the world forces of this darkness, against the spiritual forces of wickedness in the heavenly places”.

Ephesians 6:13-18 goes on to describe the spiritual armour that is necessary to overcome the forces of evil and cast out the negative influences that seek to destroy.

Answer (score 3):

The verse you are thinking of might be :

> Resist the devil and he will flee from you. James 4:7, KJV.

'Devil', in this place, being *Diabolos* in the original.

Answer (score 2):

I found these. If its Proverbs, it could be:
**Prov 13:20**

> Keep company with the wise and you will become wise. If you make friends with stupid people, you will be ruined.

Or maybe **1 Corinthians 15:33**

> Do not be fooled. “Bad companions ruin good character.”

GNB

Answer (score 1):

**Needing help locating a specific verse in the Bible about casting out bad influences?**

This whole question reminds me of the Rule of St. Benedict (chapter 28):

> [CHAPTER 28 | Of Those Who Though Often Corrected Will Not Amend](https://abbeyofreginalaudis.org/community-rule-english.htmlhttps://abbeyofreginalaudis.org/community-rule-english.html)
>
> If any brother, though often corrected for some offence and even excommunicated, do not amend, let him receive more severe correction; that is to say, let the punishment of the rod be administered to him. But if even so he do not amend, or perchance (which God forbid) being puffed up with pride would even defend his deeds, then let the abbot follow the procedure of a prudent physician. Having applied the fomentations and ointments of his exhortations, having used the medicine of the Holy Scriptures and last of all the cautery of excommunication and the strokes of the rod: then, if he see that all his trouble is of no avail, let him employ a greater thing still, namely the prayers of himself and all the brethren, that God, who can do all things, may effect the cure of the sick brother. But if he be not healed even in this way, then let the abbot use the knife of amputation, as the apostle saith: Banish the offender from your company (1 Cor. 5:13); and again: If the unbeliever depart, let him depart (1 Cor. 7:15); lest one diseased sheep contaminate the whole flock.

[1 Corinthians 5:13](https://biblehub.com/1_corinthians/5-13.htm):

> But them that are without God judgeth. Therefore put away from among yourselves that wicked person.

[1 Corinthians 7:15](https://www.godtube.com/bible/1-corinthians/7-15):

> But if the unbelieving depart, let him depart. A brother or a sister is not under bondage in such cases: but God has called us to peace.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a Christian then just recite the Lord's prayer.

It might not be dramatic or deep or 'clever' but that is what He wants us to do. In simple language let Him know that you are asking for something, that you cannot do it yourself, after all he knows us inside and out, and let Him do his work in and around us.

If you need to, then ask Him directly after the Lord's prayer, but let Him work it His way not your way like:
"Father God, if it be your grace, please remove these evil influences that are troubling me."

He knows us individually and know what we want and need. Just let Him do His work in us.
Remember, the prayer is a request and His plans are not necessarily the same as ours and it may not be in your time frame either.